# Setting file path using Clip method. Java

Tags: java

I have been wondering how to change this method so i don't have to download the song from the internet, instead i want to play the song from a directory on my computer. Can somebody please give me an example of how i would do this?

```
URL url = new URL("myUrlToSong.wav"); //How I make this a directory? 
                                      //I get an error if i change it to a string
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url); //error is here id I 
                                                             //change url to a string
clip.open(ais);
clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use any of[`AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioInputStream%28java.io.File%29) or [`AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(InputStream)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioInputStream%28java.io.InputStream%29).

```
File f = new File("mySong.wav");
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(f);
```

Or

```
InpuStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("mySong.wav"));
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(is);
```